# Как настроить поиск в Yandex Mapkit, чтобы не удалялись другие метки

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Есть следующая задача:

1. Вывести на карту множество меток из json.
2. Настроить поиск по адресу и отмечать меткой найденное.

Пункт 1 уже сделан. Пытаюсь подключить поиск [согласно данному примеру](https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yandex/mapkitdemo/SearchActivity.java). Вроде работает, но если двигать карту, то все метки ранее добавленные из json удаляются. Я понимаю, что это происходит, потому что в коде есть прямое указание на удаление, которое необходимо для работы поиска.

**Вопрос:** можно ли как-то отделить метки из json и метки, которые ставятся в результате работы поиска и удалять/добавлять только последние, а первые не трогать? Помогут ли в этом коллекции или они для другого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено посредством создания отдельной коллекции для работы с поиском:

```
// Объявление коллекции
MapObjectCollection searchObjectCollection;
...
// Добавление коллекции (в onCreate)
searchObjectCollection = mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().addCollection();
...
@Override
public void onSearchResponse(Response response) {
    searchObjectCollection.clear();
    for (GeoObjectCollection.Item searchResult : response.getCollection().getChildren()) {
        Point resultLocation = searchResult.getObj().getGeometry().get(0).getPoint();
        if (resultLocation != null) {
            searchObjectCollection.addPlacemark(resultLocation,
                        ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.search_result));
        }
    }
}
```